# Angular bind em diretiva para executar após o evento "change"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou trabalhando com um framework que utiliza Jquery para fazer suas animações, e para o tratamento de dados utilizo o AngularJS. Para que eu possa atualizar meu $scope, eu criei uma diretiva que vai dar um bind no elemento e gerar atribuir eventos a elementos nele. assim

```
element.bind('change', function () {
    console.log(e.find('div'));
});
```

O meu problema é que o angular está processando essa diretiva antes que o elemento sofra as mudanças e assim não retornando as div's existentes no final do onchange... alguém sabe como eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer que essa diretiva seja chamada após o carregamento total da view?

Comment: o que está ocorrendo é que o framework "recorta uma div e cola" em outro lugar... quando isso acontece, o angular detecta a modificação e dispara o bind, mas ele está disparando antes do "colar", ai ele acaba mandando pro console só o promise, e não a mudança